# Save and restore watir session

Tags: ruby, session, browser, watir, watir-webdriver

I want to test interactive authentication with watir. I need to open browser once on selenium server, enter without user interaction his login/password (stored on server, user doesn't enter them, he just has to enter verification code), new text field with 'enter verification code' label appears, then system sends verification code to user and closes browser(here i need somehow to save session). User receives verification code and sends it to server, server opens new browser(restores somehow saved session) and enters verification code received from user.

I could keep browser open and just enter verification code in appeared text field but if user won't send me verification code that he received, browser will remain open, not good solution.

So, I tried something like this:

```
    params = { login: 'userexample.com', password: '123456' }
    adapter = Adapters::Test.new(params)

    adapter.sign_in #opens browser, fills credentials fields, clicks 'get verification code', 'enter verification code' field appears

    cookies = adapter.browser.cookies.to_a #save browser state
    url     = adapter.browser.url
    adapter.browser.close

    adapter = Adapters::Test.new(params)
    adapter.browser.goto url

    adapter.browser.cookies.clear

    cookies.each do |saved_cookie|
      adapter.browser.cookies.add(saved_cookie[:name], saved_cookie[:value])
    end

    adapter.browser.refresh #I should be on the same page with appeared 'enter verification code' field, but nothing happens after refresh, I am still on the main page with only login/password fields.
```

How can I save browser state, close it and then reopen with the same session?

Comment: Why would the browser remain open if the user does not send the verification code? If you puts the closing of the browser in a rescue or ensure block or the test teardown, the browser would always get closed.

Comment: Anyway, in that case browser will remain open until something happens(user enters code, timeout reached). But there are too many users and selenium hub has not so many nodes to keep some of them open. Can not afford keeping idle browsers alive.

Answer (score 3):

```
  def prepare_for_sign_in
    browser.goto login_url

    browser.text_field(:name => "login").set("admin")
    browser.text_field(:name => "password").set("admin")

    browser.a(:class => "enter").click

    until browser.div(:text => /Welcome/).present? do
      if browser.div(:class => 'error').text.include?("incorrect username or password")
        raise InvalidCredentials.new("Invalid login or password.")
      end
    end

    # here you need to sleep few secs or use similar conditional wait
    Watir::Wait.until { browser.cookies.to_a.first[:name] == "JSESSIONID" }

    params["interactive_data"] = {
      "cookies" => JSON.parse(browser.cookies.to_a.to_json),
      "proceed_url" => browser.url
    }
  end

  def sign_in
    restore_cookies(params["interactive_data"]["proceed_url"])

    browser.text_field(:name => "sms").set('123456')
    browser.a(:text => "Proceed").click
  end

  def restore_cookies(url)
    browser.goto url
    browser.cookies.clear

    params["interactive_data"]["cookies"].each do |cookie|
      browser.cookies.add(
        cookie["name"],
        cookie["value"],
        {
          domain:  cookie["domain"],
          path:    cookie["path"],
          expires: cookie["expires"],
          secure:  cookie["secure"]
        }
      )
    end
    browser.goto url
    browser.refresh
  end
```

There is some more source code, but I can not share all of it, but logic is similar